# Spring Microservices - sending user data linked to created entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, microservices

Lets say I have order microservice with Order entity that has relation to user.
For example:

```
class Order {
   int orderId;
   List<Items> items;
   int **userId**;
}
```

In my case I have/want to have API Gateway microservice that is responsible for authentication and redirecting requests to proper microservice.
It is going to be something like that:
[image]
How this user data should be provided when sending request to create such entity? **Entity should be linked only with authenticated user that made this request**?

Should it be sent in the request body with other data for that entity or should user data be retrieved from the authentication data sent to server - for example from jwt token?

I would appreciate for some resources to read, this might be a stupid question but I am just starting with microservices and I have a hard time imagining how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you should be separate `user` and `customer`. The authentication server should only manage the role, permission, ... of `user`. And in the `Order Service`, you have a entity called `customer`, the `customer` will linking with `user` table in authentication server, `order` and more entity in `Order Service` like `transaction`, `invoice`, ...
Because a `user` can access to many service, but not mean the info of user in each service is the same. Like you can using a google account to login many forums (with google login)  but not mean in each forum you have the same `nickname`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but then how send costumer data? or how to.validate that customer data that was sent is proper for given authenticated user. I don't know how should I track user data within request.